# Finding flippable paths in Othello using neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## Exploring OTHELLO game logic using graphs

I am new to cypher and have been using it for the othello board game logic. I have been working on a cypher query that will return the tiles that a user can select as a next move.

### Cypher for next move

```
MATCH (g:Game)-->(empty:Tile)
WHERE g.uuid=' ' AND empty.disc='none'
WITH empty
MATCH (empty)-[direction]->(t:Tile)
WHERE t.disc = 'black'
WITH empty, direction.compass as path
MATCH p=shortestPath( (empty)-[direct:DIRECTION *]->(lastNode) )
WHERE lastNode.disc = 'white' AND direct.compass = path
RETURN empty, direct.compass
```

The error I get is on the second to last line

```
"WHERE lastNode.disc='white' AND direct.compass=path"
```

where `direct` is a collection of relationships. I am not surprised by the collection, I want to reduce that collection by filtering on the compass property to ensure all relationships are in the same direction. How do I do that?

#### Summary of what I think the logic above is trying to accomplish

I think the above code is getting all the "empty" tiles on the game board as a start. Next, filters down to the empty tiles that border black tiles. Using the empty -to- black connection I am hoping to make sure all the relationships are in the same direction when finding an ending white tile to make the path flippable.

### Game Setup

```
CREATE (g:Game { uuid: " ", player_color: "white", turn_count: "-1" })
CREATE (t0:Tile { idx: toInt(0), disc: "none" })
// Where the tiles idx[0..63] are created
CREATE (g)-[:OWNS]->(t0)
// WHERE the game owns 64 tiles idx[0..63]
CREATE (t0)-[:DIRECTION {compass:'e'}]->(t1)
// compass: ['n','ne','e','se','s','sw','w','nw']
// one relationship per direction, only to neighbors, if applicable.
// The edge of the board and corners have a subset of these.
```

I can supply the entire board creation cypher if needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reduce that collection by filtering on the compass property
>   to ensure all relationships are in the same direction. How do I do
>   that?

What you're looking for is the `ALL` predicate. So you need to tell that ALL relationships in the path `p` MUST have the property compass to a value of path :

```
WHERE ALL (x in rels(p) WHERE x.compass = path)
```

So your full WHERE line would be

```
WHERE lastNode.disc='white' AND ALL (x in rels(p) WHERE x.compass = path)
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher for pointing me to the predicate functions.